# App works on java 6 but not on java 7

Tags: java

I am creating a Java swing application - the animation of sorting and searching algorithms. I wrote the code with JDeveloper 11g release2, witch by default uses jdk 1.6, the app worked great, but after deployment i try to run it on my computer witch has jdk 1.7 and the app freezes at random moments and does not recover. I tryed out diferent pc's and opperating systems on everyone the app works great with java 6 but gets stuck if launched with java 7. I tryed to debugg it but the debugger freezes to like the app and does not unfreeze till i shut it down with windows task manager.

I managed to trace that the app freezes at the method - descriptionTA.setText(text) (the last method of the class below) when trying to set the text, sometimes it sets it correctly, but most times everything jsut stops with no error message or other life signals.

This is the class in witch the problem occurs.

```
import animatedalgorithms.MasterFrame;
import animatedalgorithms.sorting.SortAnimationComponent;
import helperclasses.ApplicationConstants;
import helperclasses.RenderedJLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class SortAnimationPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int DESCENDING_EELMENT_ORDER = 0;
    private static final int ASCENDING_ELEMEMENT_ORDER = 1;
    private static final int RANDOM_ELEMENT_ORDER = 2;

    private MasterFrame frame;
    private SortAnimationComponent comp;
    private RenderedJLabel h1;
    private JSlider algSlider;
    private JSlider animSlider;
    BackButtonComponent backBtn;
    private int elmOrder;
    private JTextArea descriptionTA ;


    public SortAnimationPanel(MasterFrame frame) {
        elmOrder = RANDOM_ELEMENT_ORDER;
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        this.frame = frame;
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        h1 = new RenderedJLabel("");
        h1.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        h1.setForeground(Color.white);

        createControls();
    }

    public void createControls() {
        // Header
        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        header.setBackground(new Color(30, 30, 30));
        header.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 5, 5));
        header.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        header.add(h1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel aboutBtn = new JPanel();
        aboutBtn.setName("aboutPanel");
        aboutBtn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        final RenderedJLabel aboutLabel = new RenderedJLabel("Apie algoritmą");
        aboutLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        aboutLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        aboutBtn.add(aboutLabel);

        header.add(aboutBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);        

        //Bottom controls
        JButton btn = new JButton("Iš naujo");
        btn.setName("replay");
        JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Rikiuoti");
        btnPlay.setName("play");
        JButton btnPause = new JButton("Pauzė");
        btnPause.setName("pause");
        JButton btnStep = new JButton("Žingsnis");
        btnStep.setName("step");
        backBtn = new BackButtonComponent();

        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        controls.setLayout(new BoxLayout(controls, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        controls.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        controls.add(btn);
        controls.add(btnPlay);
        controls.add(btnPause);
        controls.add(btnStep);
        controls.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));

        Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 30, 10);
        controls.setBorder(empty);

        JPanel labels = new JPanel();
        labels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        labels.add(new JLabel("Algoritmo greitis: "));
        labels.add(new JLabel("Animacijos greitis: "));
        labels.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        controls.add(labels);

        JPanel sliders = new JPanel();
        sliders.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        sliders.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sliders, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        algSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 100, 10000, 10000 - ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_ALGORITHM_DELAY);
        algSlider.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        algSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(2000);
        algSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(100);

        animSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 20, 10);
        animSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        animSlider.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        animSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
        sliders.add(algSlider);
        sliders.add(animSlider);
        controls.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        controls.add(sliders);

        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton eventObj = (JButton)e.getSource();
                if (eventObj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
                    comp.setToPlay();
                } else if (eventObj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pause")) {
                    comp.setToPause();
                } else if (eventObj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("replay")) {
                    resetControls();
                    switch (elmOrder) {
                    case RANDOM_ELEMENT_ORDER:
                        comp.generateRandomArray();
                        break;
                    case ASCENDING_ELEMEMENT_ORDER:
                        comp.generateAscendingArray();
                        break;
                    case DESCENDING_EELMENT_ORDER:
                        comp.generateDescendingArray();
                        break;
                    }
                    comp.resetSorter();
                    comp.startAnimation();
                } else if (eventObj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("step")) {
                    comp.step();
                }
            }
        }

        class CustomMouseListener implements MouseListener {
            boolean pressed = false;

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                pressed = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (pressed) {
                    if (e.getSource() instanceof JPanel) {
                        JFrame aboutFrame = new DescriptionFrame(comp.getAlgorithmNum());
                    } else {
                        comp.stopThread();
                        frame.setVisibleCard(MasterFrame.MENU_WINDOW);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JPanel) {
                    JPanel p = (JPanel) e.getSource();
                    p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    aboutLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
                } else {
                    BackButtonComponent comp = (BackButtonComponent)e.getSource();
                    comp.setCompColor(Color.lightGray);
                    comp.repaint();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JPanel) {
                    JPanel p = (JPanel) e.getSource();
                    p.setBackground(Color.black);
                    aboutLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
                } else {
                    BackButtonComponent comp = (BackButtonComponent)e.getSource();
                    comp.setCompColor(Color.GRAY);
                    comp.repaint();
                    pressed = false;
                }
            }
        }


        class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
                if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    if (source.getMaximum() == 20) {
                        comp.setAnimationDelay(source.getMaximum() - source.getValue());
                    } else {
                        comp.setAlgorithmStepDelay(source.getMaximum() - source.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ActionListener btnListener = new ButtonListener();
        btn.addActionListener(btnListener);
        btnPlay.addActionListener(btnListener);
        btnStep.addActionListener(btnListener);
        btnPause.addActionListener(btnListener);

        CustomMouseListener l = new CustomMouseListener();
        backBtn.addMouseListener(l);
        aboutBtn.addMouseListener(l);        

        ChangeListener sliderListener = new SliderListener();
        algSlider.addChangeListener(sliderListener);
        animSlider.addChangeListener(sliderListener);

        add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public void createLeftMenu() {

    }

    public void resetControls() {
        algSlider.setValue(algSlider.getMaximum() - ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_ALGORITHM_DELAY);
        animSlider.setValue(animSlider.getMaximum() - ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    public void loadAlgorithm(int sorterNum) {
        resetControls();

        JPanel sortPanel = new JPanel();
        sortPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        descriptionTA = new JTextArea();
        descriptionTA.setSelectionColor(Color.BLACK);
        descriptionTA.setFocusable(false);
        descriptionTA.setEnabled(true);
        descriptionTA.setRows(5);
        descriptionTA.setColumns(10);
        descriptionTA.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        descriptionTA.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        descriptionTA.setLineWrap(true);
        TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Aprašymas");
        descriptionTA.setBorder(title);

        HistoryComponent hist = new HistoryComponent(new TreeMap<String, Color>(), 30);
        TreeMap<String, Color> map = new TreeMap<String, Color>();
        switch (sorterNum) {
            case ApplicationConstants.SELECTION_SORT_NUM:
            h1.setText("Išrinkimo rikiavimo algoritmas");
            map.put("- Mažiausias elementas", ApplicationConstants.IMPORTANT_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Pasirinktas elementas", ApplicationConstants.SELECTED_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Neutralus elementas", ApplicationConstants.NEUTRAL_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Surikiuotas masyvas", ApplicationConstants.SORTED_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            hist.setMap(map);
            hist.repaint();
            comp = new SortAnimationComponent(ApplicationConstants.SELECTION_SORT_NUM, this);
            comp.setToPause();
            comp.startAnimation();
            break;
            case ApplicationConstants.BUBBLE_SORT_NUM:
            h1.setText("Burbulo rikiavimo algoritmas");
            map.put("- Pasirinktas elementas", ApplicationConstants.SELECTED_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Neutralus elementas", ApplicationConstants.NEUTRAL_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            hist.setMap(map);
            hist.repaint();
            comp = new SortAnimationComponent(ApplicationConstants.BUBBLE_SORT_NUM, this);
            comp.setToPause();
            comp.startAnimation();
            break;
            case ApplicationConstants.INSERTION_SORT_NUM:
            h1.setText("Įterpimo rikiavimo algoritmas");
            map.put("- Surikiuotas masyvas", ApplicationConstants.SORTED_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Pasirinktas elementas", ApplicationConstants.SELECTED_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Neutralus elementas", ApplicationConstants.NEUTRAL_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            hist.setMap(map);
            hist.repaint();
            comp = new SortAnimationComponent(ApplicationConstants.INSERTION_SORT_NUM, this);
            comp.setToPause();
            comp.startAnimation();
            break;
            case ApplicationConstants.QUICK_SORT_NUM:
            h1.setText("Greitojo rikiavimo algoritmas");
            map.put("- Vidurio taškas ", ApplicationConstants.IMPORTANT_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Neutralus elementas", ApplicationConstants.NEUTRAL_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Neaktyvus elementas", ApplicationConstants.INACTIVE_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            hist.setMap(map);
            hist.repaint();
            comp = new SortAnimationComponent(ApplicationConstants.QUICK_SORT_NUM, this);
            comp.setToPause();
            comp.startAnimation();
            break;
            case ApplicationConstants.MERGE_SORT_NUM:
            h1.setText("Suliejimo rikiavimo algoritmas");
            map.put("- Neutralus elementas", ApplicationConstants.NEUTRAL_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Neaktyvus elementas", ApplicationConstants.INACTIVE_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            hist.setMap(map);
            hist.repaint();
            comp = new SortAnimationComponent(ApplicationConstants.MERGE_SORT_NUM, this);
            comp.setToPause();
            comp.startAnimation();
            break;
        default:
            h1.setText("Išrinkimo rikiavimo algoritmas");
            map.put("- Mažiausias elementas", ApplicationConstants.IMPORTANT_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Pasirinktas elementas", ApplicationConstants.SELECTED_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            map.put("- Neutralus elementas", ApplicationConstants.NEUTRAL_ELEMENT_COLOR);
            hist.setMap(map);
            hist.repaint();
            comp = new SortAnimationComponent(ApplicationConstants.SELECTION_SORT_NUM, this);
            comp.setToPause();
            comp.startAnimation();
            break;
        }

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JPanel spacer = new JPanel();
        spacer.setBackground(Color.white);
        spacer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(spacer, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        spacer.add(backBtn);
        spacer.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(120));
        leftPanel.add(spacer, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel elmOrderPanel = new JPanel();
        elmOrderPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(elmOrderPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        elmOrderPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Elementų išdėstymas"));
        JButton ascBtn = new JButton("Didėjimo tvarka");
        ascBtn.setName("ascBtn");
        JButton descBtn = new JButton("Mažėjimo tvarka");
        descBtn.setName("descBtn");
        JButton randBtn = new JButton("Atsitiktine tvarka");
        randBtn.setName("randBtn");
        elmOrderPanel.add(ascBtn);
        elmOrderPanel.add(descBtn);
        elmOrderPanel.add(randBtn);
        elmOrderPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        leftPanel.add(elmOrderPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        TitledBorder colorBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Spalvų reikšmės");
        hist.setBorder(colorBorder);
        leftPanel.add(hist, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton eventObj = (JButton)e.getSource();
                if (eventObj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("randBtn")) {
                    resetControls();
                    comp.generateRandomArray();
                    comp.resetSorter();
                    comp.startAnimation();
                    elmOrder = RANDOM_ELEMENT_ORDER;
                } else if (eventObj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("descBtn")) {
                    resetControls();
                    comp.generateDescendingArray();
                    comp.resetSorter();
                    comp.startAnimation();
                    elmOrder = DESCENDING_EELMENT_ORDER;
                } else if (eventObj.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ascBtn")) {
                    resetControls();
                    comp.generateAscendingArray();
                    comp.resetSorter();
                    comp.startAnimation();
                    elmOrder = ASCENDING_ELEMEMENT_ORDER;
                }
            }
        }
        ButtonListener l = new ButtonListener();
        ascBtn.addActionListener(l);
        descBtn.addActionListener(l);
        randBtn.addActionListener(l);

        sortPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        sortPanel.add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        sortPanel.add(descriptionTA, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        sortPanel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(sortPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.updateUI();
    }

    public void setDescriptionText(String text){        
        descriptionTA.setText(text);       
    }
}
```

The setDescriptionText gets called from a nother thread that manages the animation in the panel above the JtextArea and sets the text in it.

The weird thing to me is that it works perfect with versions older than java 7.

If you need more code to detect the problem please let me know.

Comment: The kind of behavior you're seeing and the fact that your class is named SortAnimationPanel leads me to think that it's a threading problem. Make sure every access to swing components is done from the event dispatch thread, and not from a background animation thread

Comment: is there any Exception thrown by your code? or does it just stop?

Comment: Please shrink code to the minimum required. Try reducing the code as long as the problem still persists. Make sure to call `setDescriptionText` from the EDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ensure that descriptionTA.setText() is called on the EventDispatchedThread :

```
public void setDescriptionText(String text){      
    Runnable toEDT = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            descriptionTA.setText(text);    
        }
    };

    if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        toEDT.run();
    }else {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(toEDT);
    }
}
```

All UI-related operations (instanciation, modifications, etc..) should be on the EDT in order to avoid deadlocks or other funny things.

Comment: It works by accident in Java < 7. Just like riding on a small road at 180 km/h doesn't *always* lead to an accident.

Comment: I don't know, I think nobody can explain that. It is thread related things which are hard to debug and understand. Just apply this : never do something which is UI related outside of the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

Swing has a thread specially dedicated to update its GUI. So If you want to update your interface, don't call any another thread, try to update your interface with the reserved method:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // Here, we can safely update the GUI
      // because we'll be called from the
      // event dispatch thread
      statusLabel.setText("Query: " + queryNo);
    }
});
```